# Is parameter T1 really necessary in Canopy Clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, mahout

Since a point falls into range(t2, t1) will not be removed.
And the only two reasons we remove a point are:
1. Construct a new canopy with this point.
2. This point fall into range(0, t2) of another canopy.

Why do we need parameter t1?

Comment: Have you read through: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canopy_clustering_algorithm ?

Comment: I see. It makes sense if the result given by Canopy clustering is actually a preprocessed dataset instead of a final result

Comment: Traditionally one does use canopy clustering as a preprocessing, for instance to seed K-Means. So yes, you are "correct".  It depends what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Canopies are not clusters.

They are an approximation of the data set for faster processing afterwards. For this, you want canopies to *overlap*.

What you are thinking of is much older. It's called LEADER clustering. But the quality of this is so low, it never became popular.